Proof attempt for verify an Involutive function (A function such that is its own inverse): $f(x) = \pi-\sqrt{1-a}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+\cos{t}}$
I'm really stucked with this function trying to verify if $f$ is involutive: $$f(x) = \pi-\sqrt{1-a}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+\cos{t}} \quad a\leq1,\quad x,t\in\mathbb{R}$$
$f$ is an involution if and only if $$\forall x,y\in X: f(x)=y\Longrightarrow f(y) = x$$
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Involution_(Mapping)#Definition_2
My attempt:
We suppose $f(x) = y$, then $$y = \pi-\sqrt{1-a}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+\cos{t}}$$
We need to demonstrate $f(y) = x$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+\cos{t}} &= \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) &\text{By substitution}
\end{align*}
So $$f(x) = \pi-\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) =y$$
for $f(y)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
f(y) &= \pi-\sqrt{1-a}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dt}{1+\cos{t}} & \text{Definition of }f \\
     &= \pi-\sqrt{1-a}\int_{0}^{\pi-\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\frac{dt}{1+\cos{t}} & \text{Definition of }y \\
     &= \pi - \sqrt{1-a}\tan{\left(\frac{\pi-\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2}\right)} & \text{Integral by substitution}
\end{align*}
I'm going by the right way? I'm stucked in that part because I don't know how to convert that expresion into $x$ for finish the demonstration, All suggestions and commentaries are welcome.
Thank u all!

An involutive function $f:X\rightarrow X$ is such that $f\circ f = I_{X}$ where $I_{X}$ is the identity function, so, I'm trying to prove $f$ is its own inverse. Let me srite that part more clearly

It doesn't look involutive. Try $f(f(0))$

Thank you so much @Gribouillis That was a good point

Thank you so much Gribouillis! It's right, when $x=0$,
\begin{align*}
    f(x)&= \pi - \sqrt{1-a} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{1 + \cos t} &\text{Definition of } f\\
    f(0)&= \pi - \sqrt{1-a} \int_{0}^{0} \frac{dt}{1 + \cos t} & x=0 \\
        &= \pi - \sqrt{1-a}\cdot 0 & \int_{a}^{a}f = 0, \forall a\in\mathbb{R} \\
        &=\pi
\end{align*}
So  $f(f(0)) = f(\pi)$, We need to evaluate this.
\begin{align*}
    f(x)&= \pi - \sqrt{1-a} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{1 + \cos t} &\text{Def. of} f\\
    f(\pi) &= \pi - \sqrt{1-a} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dt}{1 + \cos t} & x= \pi\\
           &= \pi - \sqrt{1-a} \left.\tan{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \right|_{0}^{\pi}  & \text{Integral by substitution.} \\
           &=\pi - \sqrt{1-a}\left(\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}-\tan{\left(\frac{0}{2}\right)}\right) \\
           &=\pi - \sqrt{1-a}\cdot\color{red}\tan{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
\end{align*}
There is a problem: $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is not definied because
$$
    \lim_{x\rightarrow\pi^{+}} \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = +\infty \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow\pi^{-}} \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) = -\infty
$$
Therefore $f(f(\pi))$ doesn't exist, and  $$\exists x\in\mathbb{R} : f(f(x))\neq x$$ So this is not involutive if $f$ have as domain $\mathbb{R}$, But now, In what interval could be involutive?
